# How to use AppCenter.ms in MAUI?

Tags: maui, visual-studio-app-center

I'm trying to add `AppCenter.ms` to my MAUI application. I created a new app in the website like (as an example the screen for Android)

[image]

So, in my `MauiProgram.cs` I added before the `return builder.Build();` the following code:

```
AppCenter.Start("ios={mycode};" +
        "windowsdesktop={mycode};" +
        "android={mycode};" +
        "macos={mycode};",
        typeof(Analytics), typeof(Crashes));
```

For Windows and Android, the application is working and I can see some logs in the website. It doesn't work for iOS and MacCatalyst and I get similar errors:

For MacCatalyst:

> The type initializer for 'Microsoft.AppCenter.Utils.ApplicationLifecycleHelperDesktop' threw an exception."

[image]
[image]

For iOS:

> "Could not create an native instance of the type 'Microsoft.AppCenter.Apple.Bindings.MSACWrapperSdk': the native class hasn't been loaded. It is possible to ignore this condition by setting ObjCRuntime.Class.ThrowOnInitFailure to false."

[image]
[image]

I saw few chats on [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/discussions/3333) but I don't understand if Microsoft continues the support of `AppCenter.ms` also for MAUI applications. Also, I read the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/getting-started/xamarin#421-maui-and-xamarinforms) and followed what it says.

Is it possible to have the *Analytics* and *Crashes* functionalities working for iOS and macCatalyst or it is better to use different tools?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I removed the packages, added them back. Then, I cleaned the solution and deleted bin/obj folders. Appcenter was loaded correctly after a nuget restore.

Comment: I tried a lot of times to uninstall and reinstall the package but no success.

Comment: I did it using rider. I worked after deleting bin/obj and performing package restore